# laravel jenssegers mongodb whereraw regex integer type not working

Tags: laravel, mongodb

i am NOT getting result thought the data is there in DB

```
 $conditions = collect($this->getColumns())->map(function ($column, $key) use ($keyword, $or_conditions) {
            return $or_conditions[] =  [
                $column => [
                 '$regex' => "$keyword",
                 '$options' => 'i'
                ],
            ];
        });
        $final_or_condition = [
            '$or' => $conditions->toArray()
        ];
        $this->collection = $this->collection->whereRaw($final_or_condition);
```

when i search in Datatable input field on type integer field in mongoDB collection return results null if regex field return only for string what is alternative as the condition is in LOOP

Comment: What's the value of `$keyword` here?

Comment: @apokryfos its string from search input but in collection its integer which results null but in string type it gives  records

Comment: @apokryfos how can i apply like query on above loop condition using whereRaw ?

Comment: I believe that whereRaw method expects a SQL string as a parameter, not an array.

Comment: @AlexandrBlyakher its working fine on string type but not with integer i need solution on like query with integer type field

Comment: @AlexandrBlyakher but thing is regex only match strings and return data so if i change same field value TYPE from int to string it works

Comment: MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive.  Regular expressions match only strings, not any other data type.

Comment: @Joe so dear any other solution  ?

Comment: Depends on what you expecting to happen when querying a number with a regex.  One option is to change the data type that is stored in the database to string, so the regex match will work.